# Random Number in MySQL column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add random number in one of my database column called likes which have about 5000 row in it. currently I have tried like below to get random number from 10 to 50.

```
$randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
```

but this is setting same number in all row...instead I want different number in row...anyone can please suggest how can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code as to how you are setting that random  number?

Comment: `$randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));` doesn't do anything to your database; it just sets a PHP variable. Please show us more code.

Comment: This question is way too unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `UPDATE Table SET fieldName = ((rand() * 1000) % 40) + 10;`

Because when you preset it in a variable, it'll be the same for all...

Comment: `UPDATE Table SET randomnumberlike = rand(10,50);` - you realize that that will update their entire database. Unless that's what they want. Edit: Oh, and that's an error. Best to assign a variable to it first @EvgenyKolyakov then use it in the query after.

Comment: Yes... the rest of the `WHERE` is up to his decision ...

Comment: We'll see what the OP has to say. I myself found the question to be unclear.

Comment: I am getting error like this #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'rand'

Comment: try `((rand() * 1000) % 40) +10`

Comment: This is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a variable:

```
$randomnumberlike = (rand(10,50));
```

If you're then using $randomnumberlike to add to the db then it will always be the same, its already be assigned (unless within a loop), you need to use `(rand(10,50))` (or working similar) directly in the query like this:

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET <field_name> = ROUND((RAND() * (50-10))+10) WHERE ...;
```